# How can I find lines of a certain angle(s)?

Tags: image-processing

`ImageLines` implements the Hough transform, but how do I search for only lines within some threshold of a certain angle(s)?

Comment: Could you please post some sample images, code you have written so far? You might try to find all the lines and simply take the ones within your threshold.

Comment: You could do the Radon transform which allows specification of the range over which to look.

Comment: There's a `Radon` function might be a start point.

Comment: An explanation and example appear in an [answer on the stats site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33078/data-has-two-trends-how-to-extract-independent-trendlines/33102#33102).

Comment: Angle from what, horizontal?

Comment: @J.M. sure, assume horizontal lines are 0 degrees

Answer (score 3):

To search only for lines at given angles, say between theta0 and theta1, you could:

1. Compute the Hough transform using `Radon[img, dims, {theta0, theta1}, Method -> "Hough"]`
2. Detect peaks in the Hough transform, ie. the local maxima with high values (`MaxDetect` and `Binarize` may help, for example)
3. Extract the positions of the detected peaks and convert them from the image coordinate systems to {rho, theta} values (`Rescale` may help)